# php strcmp method doesn't return 0 while parameters equal?

Tags: php

I use `strcmp()` for string comparison. I give the same value to the parameters, but it doesn't return 0, so my comparison fails. The relevant code snippet:

```
fwrite($fh ,"\n".$mevcutyoutubeid. "\n");
fwrite($fh , $youtubeid. "\n");
if($mevcutyoutubeid=!null){
    fwrite($fh ,"null degil");
    if(strcmp(trim($mevcutyoutubeid),trim($youtubeid )) == 0){
        echo"xxx"
    }
```

In my file these are the written ids:

```
UCcJWloZ7QDD1v0hdbQkosVw
UCcJWloZ7QDD1v0hdbQkosVw
```

So, they're exactly the same. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
 if($mevcutyoutubeid=!null){
```

That's not a comparison (`!= null`); that's an assignment (`= !null`). An assignment to `!null` doesn't really make any sense, by the way—[it evaluates to `true`](https://3v4l.org/bTnCX), but there's no good reason to do that. Anyway, that assignment breaks the following logic.

That said, your question is pretty unclear because (1) the code wasn't formatted coherently (I've fixed that) and (2) most of your code is completely irrelevant to the problem. In the future, please use proper formatting, include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and eliminate anything not essential to the question.

Comment: It's not always obvious what's essential to the question. Imagine if he thought the `if` statement was not important, you'd have never found the actual problem.

Comment: @Barmar It's true that it's not always obvious, but sometimes it really is obvious. The `fwrite()` statements before the comparison have no relevance to the comparison at issue. Take a look at the [first revision of the post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41067667/1); it was challenging even to see what was happening. Anyway, the point isn't to criticize, but to encourage OP to try to narrow down the problem before posting.